# SSIS special characters in column name

Tags: ssis

In SSIS I need to import data from table, that has column names like this N°Projet, PR Réalisé. During set up of OLE DB Source everything is OK. I can run this package from Visual Studio and load data. But when I deploy the project and set up sql server job to run it, I get error.
I can see that query in OLE DB Source has changed.

What I set up:

```
SELECT 
[N°Projet] AS ProjectNumber
,[N°Projet] AS CurrentProjectNumber
,[Projet] AS ProjectName
```

What I see when I recreate SSIS project from sql catalog

```
SELECT 
    [NÂ°Projet] AS ProjectNumber
    ,[NÂ°Projet] AS CurrentProjectNumber
    ,[Projet] AS ProjectName
```

And therefor my query in OLE DB Source is invalid.

Any idea how to fix this issue without changing source table columns?